# Xcode закрыть документ без сохранения

Tags: xcode

Не могу найти как в Xcode отключить автоматическое сохранение файлов, или хотя бы как при закрытие файла сказать что его не нужно сохранять.
Нашел File->Revert to Saved, но у меня почему то это не работает: "The document “main.m” could not be reverted."
Очень напрягает постоянно перед закрытием долго долго нажимать Command+Z, иногда еще и проскакиваю последнее сохранение и приходится еще возвращать отмененное  :)

Comment: Мне не понятно зачем это надо. Взяли да сделали git reset.

Comment: Ну во первых это лишнее тело движение. А во вторых Вы правда думаете, что у всех все проекты лежат в Git?? Или тем кто этого не делает и xcode открывать не стоит? :)

Comment: Да, наверное, я кейс не понимаю, когда это нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ApplePersistence -bool no
```

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря Вам, я нашел вот это: Turn System Preferences -> General -> "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" on.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468313/how-to-disable-auto-save-in-xcode-4-6